# Is "The only invariant for me is change" proper English, if not, how to correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The only invariant for me is the change

I write this sentence and hope to show that the frequency of my changes is very high(IOW, I often make changes). But I don't know is it proper. BTW, how native English speakers express this?

Comment: Not a native speaker, but I don't find any problem! However, I'd write - The only invariant *to* me is *'change.'* I'd not put the article.

Comment: You might add the context and where you are using this. I don't think *invariant* is generally used. I would write: "The only *constant* for me is change." In any case, *change* is a quality and not a countable noun, so no article is used..